# When a 7-membered ring is formed during GC/MS, does the substituent need to start with a carbon?

Tags: organic-chemistry, spectroscopy

When looking at the GC/MS for Allylthiobenzene aka allyl phenyl sulphide, two clear peaks are seen at 91 m/z and 65 m/z, most common for 7 membered and 5 membered carbon rings respectively. The problem is that the substituent group associated to this compound begins with a sulphur, which, when integrated into the ring, does not produce a signal at 91. Is it possible for this to be cleaved and a different carbon (possibly from the tail swinging around) to be integrated?

Comment: Welcome to chemSE. The likely cations mz=65 and m/z=91 are $\ce{C5H5+}$ and $\ce{C7H7+}$ (tropylium?), respectively. There is the possibility that the initial event is a Claisen rearrangement. This would form a $\ce{C10}$ framework from which the fragments arise.

Comment: It is also true that the MS of toluene, thioanisole and allylbenzene all show the presence of m/z=65 and m/z=91 fragments. [Look here](https://sdbs.db.aist.go.jp/sdbs/cgi-bin/direct_frame_top.cgi).